Is a root .project file required for RTC/Jazz?
My company has many repositories that all have the same structure:
root folder (no .project file but it does contain a few source-controlled files)
  +-- server folder (.project file)
  +-- client folder (.project file)

Developers only need to import "server" and "client" projects into Eclipse to do the vast majority of their work.
Years ago, back when we moved to RTC/Jazz, someone added an Eclipse .project file to the root folder of every single repo. This file is empty except for the project name. It is not used in day-to-day development. So now, every project looks like this:
root folder (.project file)
  +-- server folder (.project file)
  +-- client folder (.project file)

I'm trying to track down why this root .project file was added, and something makes me think it's related to our move to RTC/Jazz. Unfortunately, the people who likely made the change no longer work here, and we no longer use RTC/Jazz so I can't ask them or check the manual or the change history or ask a question in the Jazz.net forum.
I tried asking the remaining members of our DevOps team and also searching the Jazz.net forum, but no luck so far. It's perhaps implied by this question but I'm not sure. I'm hoping some with an active instance of RTC/Jazz can tell me.
Is this an RTC/Jazz thing or am I barking up the wrong tree?
